# changing imageview image inside a loop in android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

i have some imageviews in my project with this id's: stagebtn_1,stagebtn_2,stagebtn_3 and...

by default all of them points to an image nad works perfectly...
now i want to change picture of some of them inside in a loop with this code:

```
for (int i=1;i<=3;i++) {
        int imageViewId = getResources().getIdentifier("stagebtn_" + i, "id", "com.english.game");
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(imageViewId);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic1);
    }
```

but it doesnt work in the way that i want, this code doesnt change pictures, instead creates 3 new imageview with new picture...

how i can solve this?

Comment: so you have images inside drawable than use Integer to get it

Comment: @Rstar: how? can you give me an example? whats my wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this way

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 ImageView imageView;

 Integer[] image = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.tmp,R.drawable.android };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.splash);

   imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

   for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        imageView.setImageResource(image[i]);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but this code is for changing only one image view not? because this code is out of loop:
 imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

please help me

Comment: this is change 3 images and you can only see last one  , use post Delayed to increase interval time